# "Ой ты гой еси..."

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов, история

Что значит *гой*? Каково происхождение этого слова?

Answer (score 5):

А ничего не значит.
Междометие усилительного плана.
Происходит от древнерусского морфа "жить", "жизнь", "жизненные силы".
Созвучие с "гой" ("нееврей") чисто случайно.

[Гой еси | ru.wikipedia.org](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B8)

Невозможность иной трактовки обсуждалась на форумах неоднократно

посмотрите здесь, например:
http://forum.gramota.ru/forum/read.php?f=6&i=283&t=178

Comment: Междометие? :0
"Ой ты ах еси"? "Ой ты ведь еси"?

Извините, но такая версия кажется мне несостоятельной. В данной конструкции "гой" явно существительное. Тем более, что в современном языке сохранилось противоположное "изгой". "Гой" - "член общины", это, пожалуй, ближе к истине. "Наш человек".

Comment: Созвучие с "гой" ("нееврей") чисто случайно.

Тогда какой смысл вкладывают евреи в слово "гой"? Или это лучше оформить отдельным вопросом?

Comment: Это конечно, отдельный вопрос, но не стоит он отдельной темы, я отвечу. 
"Гой"  это "нееврей". Этим все сказано и этим исчерпывается. Причем никакого неодобрительного смысла исходно не несло, он появился позже. Изначально, вроде бы, означало даже не человека, а любое чуждое племя.

Comment: Поскольку Вам известен исходный смысл, не могли бы Вы рассказать подробнее, какова этимология этого слова? Оно из иврита?

Comment: "Причем никакого неодобрительного смысла исходно не несло, он появился позже."

В самом деле? Какой именно?

Comment: У меня такое ощущение, что вы хотите не узнать, а о чем-то поведать. Нет?

Comment: А слово **"еси"** что значит? 

Это, наверное, глагол "есть" применительно к слову "ты"? Т.е. 2 лицо, ед. число?

Comment: > Т.е. 2 лицо, ед. число
Всё бы нечего, но "еси" форма неизменная, что ты - гой еси, что вы - гой еси... Именно все эти особенности и заставили меня назвать всю конструкцию междометием.  
Откуда оно взялось именно в такой форме, признаться, не разобрался до конца, хотя пытался неоднократно.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых,
"с корнем гой связано сохраняющееся в современном языке слово изгой (от изжити). Оно в древнерусском языке было социальным термином и означало лицо, «изжитое», «выжитое», то есть утратившее связь со своей социальной средой.[6][7]

Опираясь на подобное значение слова изгой, некоторые исследователи трактуют формулу гой еси как знак принадлежности к общине (роду, племени, нации, расе): «Ты есть наш, наших кровей»".(Wiki)

Во-вторых, 
 "еврейское слово «гой» (ивр. גוי‎, мн.число גויים гойи́м), начиная со Средних веков означает нееврея-иноверца, как правило, христианина. Этимология слова «гой» восходит к древнееврейскому «гой» («народ»)."[link text](http://arc.familyspace.ru/catalog/goj)

Что мы имеем? Значение схоже, форма полностью совпадает. Вывод: это одно и то же слово. Вероятно,в иврите является заимствованием из одного из индоевропейских языков.

Comment: Заметьте, что в Википедии в вашем втором абзаце нет ни одной ссылки на источник. Утверждение вполне могло быть оригинальным исследованием, где "некоторые исследователи" следует понимать как "автор сих строк".